Visualising the marginals of a random variable/ barren plateaus
First of all, I'm ashamed to admit it, but I'm rusty on my probability theory.
I'm trying to get my head around this paper, and there they introduce the following cost function: $${C}_{{\rm{G}}}=1-\mathop{\prod }\nolimits_{j = 1}^{n}{\cos }^{2}\frac{{\theta }^{j}}{2}$$ 
Now, the $\theta_i$s are drawn uniformly at random from $[0,2\pi]$, and each of the thetas are assumed to be independent.
I'm trying to get my head around how they are visualising this. Clearly, they aren't considering a cross-section where all but $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are chosen to be zero, because the graph wouldn't depend on $n$. I think they are working with the marginal and are doing a calculation like
$$\left( \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\theta}{2}  \right) d\theta\right)^{n-2}$$ to work out the marginal.
So, I think we are effectively scaling the axes to account for the fact that we are drawing the rest of the variables at random.
My question is: what is the expression for this function of $\theta_1, \theta_2$, and is my intuition right?
